# Antonym of aspect

Tags: antonyms

One of the meanings of *aspect*, and I believe, one of its more original ones, is the observable or exposed side, or appearance of an object from a specific angle of view. That meaning has tended to wane in common usage but survives in specialized usage, as in the aspect of a building (architecture) or the aspect of a planet (astrology).

I am looking for an antonym of *aspect* in that sense, as in the parts of an object which are *invisible* from a specific angle of view. If it exists at all, it might contain the root *-spect* as well, with an appropriate prefix.

However, I need to use the term figuratively so I'm also open to approximations. For example, the inside of an apparently solid object is invisible from all external angles of view and may possess a name that is analogous (but opposite) to *aspect*.

Comment: Since the _*spek-_ part means "to observe" from PIE, it's probably unlikely to have that suffix. See https://www.etymonline.com/word/aspect#etymonline_v_17943

Comment: *Invisible* etymologically refers to sight, if only to negate it. However, as I said, *-spect* doesn't have to be in there; it's just a suggestion.

Comment: Mmm. Unfortunately _dispect_ isn't a real word, as _dis-_ is a possible antonym for _ad-_.

Comment: “Unrelated parts”

Comment: It would be similar to *occult*, in its astronomical acceptation.

Comment: I've decide to use *topside* and *underside*, until someone comes up with a better alternative.